# What's wrong with this program - nothing happens?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am an absolute beginner in python programming (week 4), and I'm trying to figure this out. I've been going at this for days now but I am truly stuck. I've debugged it to zero errors, but when I run, nothing happens...at all. What am I doing wrong here?

```
roster =[]

def init_(self, name):
  self.name = name

def setName (self,name):
  self.name = name

def getName(self):
  return self.name

def displayData(self):
  print("")
  print(" Player's Information")
  print("***********************")
  print("Player's Name: ", self.name)

def displayMenu():
  print("***Selection Menu***")
  print("1. View current roster")
  print("2. Add a player to the roster")
  print("2. Remove a player from the roster")
  print("3. Change a player name displayed on the roster")
  print("4. Quit")
  print()
  return int(input("Your Choice?"))

def viewRoster():
  print(' '.join(roster))

def addPlayer():
  newName = input("Who will bring honor to the squad?:")
  roster.append(newName)

def removePlayer ():
  removeName = input("Who's off the team?")
  if removeName in roster:
    del roster[removeName]
  else:
    print("Sorry", removeName, "is not on this team")

def editPlayer():
  oldName = input("What name would you like to change? ")
  if oldName in roster:
    newName = input("What is the new name?  ")
    print("Alright,", oldName, "is now called", newName)
  else:
    print("Sorry,", oldName, "was not found. Are you sure you spelled that right?")
```

Comment: You've `def`ined a bunch of functions, but you haven't *called* any of them.

Comment: You have told Python how to do a bunch of things, but you haven't told Python to do any of them.

Comment: The functions also appear to be methods, but I don't see any class declaration.

Comment: None of these functions look like an entry point into your program. There seems to be a large amount of code still missing.

Answer (score -1):

The biggest problem in your code is that though you have defined a lot of functions, you have not called a single one.

Also, the first function should be

```
def __init__(self, name):
```

Next up, you need to define a class to encapsulate all your functions and the roster variable. Since it is a class, you add self. in front of your variables like roster.

Then you can import this class elsewhere and call the functions.